# Running multiple rails app using passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am hosting a Rails app using passenger and nginx.

I have an `nginx.conf` with a working server block for the first app that looks somewhat like this.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app1.example.com www.app1.example.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  root /home/ec2-user/app1/public;
}
```

However, I want to deploy a second rails app and on the same `nignx.conf` wrote:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app2.example.com www.app2.example.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  root /home/ec2-user/app2/public;
}
```

I think there is a conflict with the the ports but I am having trouble finding answers to solving this.

Comment: Looks fine.  What does the nginx error log say

Comment: I am still new to nginx and passenger. Please show me where to find error logs. All I can say right now is browsers can visit the first app but the second app could not be found. The first app is running on port 3000. Ultimately, I am trying to run the second app on port 3010.

Comment: I would check in /var/log

Comment: There is an `nginx` directory in this path. However, I found no errors logs in this folder dated today when I started working on this. I checked the date on my server and it is current. The `error.log` file is also empty.

Comment: ok do you have an `error_log` line in nginx.conf?

Comment: I didn't. I just uncommented it, saved, and restarted nginx. I tried to access the site but no errors were logged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57008/discussion-between-user1584575-and-baloo).